# How to change Image brightness by range of black and white mask in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two images :

```
Mat originalImage = imread(addr, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
Mat maskImage = imread(addr, 0);
```

[Originl Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wl0g.jpg)
[Mask Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpnmN.jpg)

maskImage is a grayscale image and size of both images are same.
My question is how can I change brightness in my image by the mask that I have in opencv c++?
We have a range between 0 than 255 and 0 it means don't change brightness and 255 is maximum brightness.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which openCV version you are using. Have you looked up the OpenCV API? There should be a method to overlay images.

Comment: You mean you want to multiply maskImage's brightness(0~1) pixel to original image(0~255) pixel?

Comment: Yes if it possible or something fast like it

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [How to change brightness of an image](https://answers.opencv.org/question/193276/how-to-change-brightness-of-an-image-increase-or-decrease/)
the code written in python but you can use the c++ API

Comment: Thank you but we have convertto method in opencv to increase or decrease the brightness but it doesn't work with a mask and I think the link that you put is same as convertto method in opencv and it doesn't work with a mask.